# X ray diffraction and the band theory

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, phonons, x-rays

I was look around stack exchange and couldn't find a good answer to this: What is the relation of the band theory of solids and the X-ray diffraction? We know that it EM wave is scattered (the process is difraction from reflection [diffraction grating]) only if there is a vector in reciprocal lattice such that $\Delta k=G$. But how can this be explained from the band theory? Is it possible to explain from phonons? How does this interaction occur?

Any hint is very appreciated.

Comment: Well, actually, the processes of reflection and diffraction both come out of solving the EM equations under the appropriate boundary/volume conditions. Now, in a solid, the electron density is a function of $k$, so one expects that this modulation will get picked up in some components of the EM response, namely those parts that are diffracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X-ray diffraction is caused by deep, very atomic like electronic orbitals. These deep orbitals are tightly bound so they have resonance frequencies in the X-ray domain. The dielectric response can be found to a very good approximation from the sum of the atomic polarisabilities at each lattice site. This is why the response shows Bragg diffraction. Valence electrons, the subject of band structure calculations, contribute very little. Phonons are meV scale phenomena to be compared to the x-rays energy if multiple keV. Phonons may cause some broadening of the Bragg diffraction peaks because thermal motion affects the atomic positions.

Comment: so there the change in momentum has nothing to do with colisions with electrons or phonons? I thought it could have because since it undergoes a change in momentum, that change has to be performed by something... That is, if there is conservation of momentum, and the scattered wave is different, then "who" gets the momentum to "compensate" the change?

Comment: @Bidon as this answer explains, the interaction is with the inner-shell electrons; any momentum transfer goes through them - but it ultimately ends up shared with the ionic lattice and the solid as a whole.